# Condition for showing Home screen after Auth screen is not working as expected

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I check for a `firebaseUser`, the print says that there is an active `firebaseUser` but the app will still load the `Auth` screen and not the `Home` screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use FutureBuilder to reload widget :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgubQ.png

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `FutureBuilder` but in your code, the `currentUser()` is asynchronous, therefore even if there is a user it will call `Auth()` since it is getting executed even before the `currentUser()` finishes execution, you should do the following:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then((user){
 if(user != null){
     return Home();
   } else{
     return Auth();
   }
 });
```